# Unable to resolve service for type 'IMediatorHandler' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.AdminController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

It's my first time working with .net api and I'm experiencing a dependency injection problem

I got a project with the following public interface that implements methods of other classes, but doesn't have a class for it

**IMediatorHandler**

```cs
    public interface IMediatorHandler
    {
        Task RaiseEvent<T>(T @event) where T : Event;

        Task<CommandResponse<TData>> SendCommand<TData>(ICommand command);

        Task<ICommandResponse> SendCommand<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : class, ICommand;

        Task<CommandResponse<TData>> SendCommand<TCommand, TData>(TCommand command) where TCommand : class, ICommand;

        Task<QueryResponse<TData>> SendQuery<TData>(IQuery query);

        Task<QueryResponse<TData>> SendQuery<TQuery, TData>(TQuery query) where TQuery : class, IQuery;

        Task<IQueryResponse> SendQuery<TQuery>(TQuery query) where TQuery : class, IQuery;
    }
```

Because of this, the swagger is accusing the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IMediatorHandler' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.AdminController'.

I was told to use addSingleton but I don't know how to put it in Startup.cs since the interface doesn't have a defined class

**QueryResponse**

```cs
public class QueryResponse<TData> : IQueryResponse, IResponse, IResponse<TData>
    {
        public TData Data
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual Exception Exception
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public virtual bool Success
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public QueryResponse(TData data)
            : this(success: true)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        protected QueryResponse(bool success)
        {
            Success = success;
        }

        public virtual TException GetException<TException>() where TException : Exception
        {
            return (TException)Exception;
        }

        public TQueryResponse SetException<TQueryResponse>(Exception ex) where TQueryResponse : IQueryResponse
        {
            SetException(ex);
            return (TQueryResponse)(object)this;
        }

        public void SetException(Exception ex)
        {
            Success = false;
            Exception = ex;
        }
    }
```

**CommandResponse**

```cs
public class CommandResponse<TData> : ICommandResponse, IResponse, IResponse<TData>
    {
        public TData Data
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual Exception Exception
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public virtual bool Success
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public CommandResponse(TData data)
            : this(success: true)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        protected CommandResponse(bool success)
        {
            Success = success;
        }

        public virtual TException GetException<TException>() where TException : Exception
        {
            return (TException)Exception;
        }

        public TCommandResponse SetException<TCommandResponse>(Exception ex) where TCommandResponse : ICommandResponse
        {
            SetException(ex);
            return (TCommandResponse)(object)this;
        }

        public void SetException(Exception ex)
        {
            Success = false;
            Exception = ex;
        }
    }
```

**AdminController**

```cs
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    [ApiController, Route("[controller]")]
    public class AdminController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediatorHandler mediatorHandler;

        public AdministracaoController(IMediatorHandler mediatorHandle)
        {
            this.mediatorHandler = mediatorHandle;
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("Command")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(List<ValidationFailure>))]
        public async Task<IResponse> Command([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MediatorHandlerBinder))] ICommand command)
        {
            return await this.mediatorHandler.SendCommand(command);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Query")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(List<ValidationFailure>))]
        public async Task<IResponse> Query([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MediatorHandlerBinder))] IQuery query)
        {
            return await this.mediatorHandler.SendQuery(query);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestion?

Comment: You will always be required to make a concrete implementation of the IMediatorHandler interface for each lifetime and in order to register it with your dependency container. Making a dependency registration using an interface is a generally good idea, as you can later change or make a new concrete implementation for that interface, forcing you to only update the registration and keep all existing code as is.

Comment: Regarding your singleton remark, you should read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetimes) regarding lifetimes and choose what best suites your need for the IMediatorHandler.

Comment: There's no way for DI to know what you're expecting if you don't wire it up to a concrete implementation. You can register concretes without an interface but not the other way around.

Comment: An interface says "If you create a class that implements me, it's guaranteed to have these methods or properties." It doesn't do anything by itself. There must be a class.

Comment: Reading the documentation and looking at forums I could see that it makes no sense to have an interface without implementation since then it is just a service promise. I used visual studio code and visual studio but neither shows a class implementing this interface by global search

Comment: And if so, I would have to create the class to implement this interface, correct?

Comment: Yes. But I'd want to be sure - did someone really create this interface and not implement it? I'd try to find out if that's really the case. If they didn't then I'd question whether you should just start implementing it as-is. If there's no implementation, there might be methods no one uses, so why do the work of implementing them. What if nothing uses the interface at all? I'd try to make sense of that before going any further.

Comment: I will do this investigation. Thank you all for your help